# Animate RecyclerView items one by one

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm trying to animate my `RecyclerView` items in my app. I tried using this code in my adapter:

```
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        myHolder = holder as MyView;
        if (position > mCurrentPosition)
        {
            int currentAnim = Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft;
            SetAnimation(holder.ItemView, currentAnim);
            mCurrentPosition = position;
        }

    }

    private void SetAnimation(View view, int currentAnim)
    {

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(mContext, currentAnim);
        anim.SetInterpolator(mContext, Android.Resource.Interpolator.Bounce);
        view.StartAnimation(anim);
    }
```

However, because all of my items appear together when the view is created, and not added when the user clicks a button, for example, all of the items animate together.

I want the items to animate one after the other, in the order of their position.
How is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    myHolder = holder as MyView;
    if (position > mCurrentPosition)
    {
        Handler h = new Handler();
        int currentAnim = Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft;
        Action myAction = () => 
        {
            SetAnimation(holder.ItemView, currentAnim);
        };

        h.PostDelayed(myAction, 1000);


        mCurrentPosition = position;
    }

}
```

**Update**: if you want to animate all items in order, you should put logic code out side an adapter.
For example, in activity, after set adapter for RecyleView

```
   List<YourObject> data; // your data list for RecycleView

   // CALL this code after set adapter for RecycleView
   Handler h = new Handler();
   int currentAnim = Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft;
   Action myAction = () => 
   {     
      // assume you use LinearLayoutManager  for RecyecleView
        View itemView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(0);
        StartAnimation(itemView, 0);
   };

   h.PostDelayed(myAction, 1000);


   private void StartAnimation(View view, int position)
    {

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(mContext, currentAnim);
        anim.SetInterpolator(mContext, Android.Resource.Interpolator.Bounce);
        view.StartAnimation(anim);
        anim.AnimationEnd += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // animate next item

            ++position;
            if (position < data.size()) // data is your array list
            {

                // assume you use LinearLayoutManager  for RecyecleView
                View itemView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
                if (itemView != null)
                {
                    StartAnimation(itemView, position);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It animates all of the items together.

Comment: Perhaps it is because I add my items from code one after each other?

Comment: @amitairos I updated my answer. If you want to animate in order, you can use my sample code (it may not work, you have to check by yourself).

Comment: Thanks!!! It works like a charm. One revision I added- I set the itemView's default visibility to gone, and before calling StartAnimation I set it to visibile. Otherwise, it would appear and then animate. Now it animates before it appears.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add delay time to your animation and increment the delay every item bind.

```
int delayAnimate = 300; //global variable

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //set view to INVISIBLE before animate
    holder.viewAnimate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    setAnimation(holder.ll_root);
}

private void setAnimation(final View view) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            if(view!=null){
                view.startAnimation(animation);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }, delayAnimate);
    delayAnimate+=300;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        // animate here
    }, DURATION * position)
}
```

DURATION * position helps to animate recyclerview items one by one.
DURATION is best when set between 50-75.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer, but it might help. I think you should set a delay between your animations.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
     // your code that you want to delay here
   }
}, 1000/* 1000ms = 1sec delay */);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Xamarin, so it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code add in **onBindViewHolder**

```
      @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainActiviy.PostsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Post model)
        {


            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(holder.itemView.getContext(),android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            holder.itemView.setAnimation(animation);
            
          

        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).